# Navigation in Compose in the very beginning

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I am aware of most of navigation handling in Compose, but just curious to know how to change the starting screen based on some dynamic login.

Currently my code is like this

```
WeatherWalaTheme {
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalDependencyContainer provides dependencyContainer
            ) {
                DestinationsNavHost(navGraph = NavGraphs.root)
            }
        }
```

And here the first screen is automatically the one which has start = true for Root navigation graph. But I want to go to different screen based on the API Response on this activity which contains this code.

Comment: How does your app start? Do you show some kind of loading screen as the first screen? Or a splashscreen which is displayed until you have the response?

Comment: Yes I am showing a splashScreen which is displayed until I have the response. I am using the new SplashScreen API by Google.

Comment: What is the difference between `DestiantionsNavHost` and a normal `NavHost`? The normal NavHost has an overload where you can specify your starting decision.

Comment: Yes that starting overload is working fine thank you. DestinationsNavHost is almost the something as NavHost, in fact it is also NavHost, but it is part of Destinations library which makes navigation much easier in JetPack Compose. Thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal `NavHost` has an overload where you can specify a starting destination.